# SQL query for finding the latest sale price for an item for a customer

Tags: sql, sapb1

Hi I have the following data set generated from database (of a SAP Business One system)

[image: Dataset]

I generated this result by using the following query:

```
SELECT T1.[ItemCode], T0.[DocNum], T1.[Price], T0.[CardName] 
FROM OINV T0  INNER JOIN INV1 T1 ON T0.[DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry]
GROUP BY T1.[ItemCode], T1.[Price], T0.[CardName],T0.[DocNum]
```

I want to grab the latest price of each item for each customer.
Can anyone please help me with that?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please provide a sample input and output data. What is `customer` in your table? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
SELECT T1.[ItemCode], T0.[DocNum], T1.[Price], T0.[CardName],
row_number() over(partition by T0.[CardName],T1.[ItemCode] order by T1.[Price] desc) as rn
FROM OINV T0  INNER JOIN INV1 T1 ON T0.[DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry]
)A where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `OINV.CardName` as there can be different cardnames for the same customer in `OINV-table`, if you change the name in BP-masterdata, or the same name for multiple businesspartners. Use `T0.CardCode` or `join OCRD on OINV.CardCode` and, if required, get the name from `OCRD`.

Also, if you order by price, you only get the lowest but not the latest price, so if you want to order it, go for `OINV.DocDate DESC` or `OINV.DocEntry DESC` to get the price from latest by date or by added document.